# Terraform template doesn't replace variables by value

Tags: terraform

I would like to fill template by values, but I have the identical content to the template.

A result should be something like this in file `hosts.yaml`. The template isn't finished yet and is going to be edited.

```yaml
rnd_hetzner:
  hosts:
    rnd.test:
      ansible_port: 22
      ansible_host: 1.1.2.3
```

**Template:**

```
# Ansible Inventory
---

all:
  hosts:
{% for instance, details := instances_ips.value %}
    {{ instance }}:
      ansible_host: {{ details.external_ip }}
{% endfor %}

  children:
    all_servers:
      hosts:
{% for instance, _ := instances_ips.value %}
        {{ instance }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Terraform**

```
locals {
  instances_ips = {
    "value" : {
      "app-server" : {
        "external_ip" : "1.27.1.1"
      },
      "db-server" : {
        "external_ip" : "1.24.9.1"
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "local_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/ansible_inventory.tpl",
    {
      instances_ips = jsonencode(local.instances_ips)
    }
  )
  filename = "${path.module}/templates/hosts.yaml"
}
```

Comment: This `:=` is not correct syntax. Additionally, the template format is wrong.

Comment: To expand on the above comment: HCL2 template language/rendering is not equivalent to Sprig or Jinja2. A good initial document for perusal would be https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile#examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [the advice in the `templatefile` docs about how to generate valid JSON or YAML](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template), here's an idiomatic way to do it.

The template consists of a single call to `yamlencode` with the data structure described using Terraform's own expression language. This ensures that the result is always valid YAML without any need for special escaping:

```
# Ansible Inventory
---
${yamlencode({
  hosting = {
    hosts = {
      for inst in instancesips : inst.hostname => {
        ansible_port = 222
        ansible_host = inst.external_ip
      }
    }
  }
})}
```

The Terraform configuration would be similar to the following:

```
data "vultr_instance" "instance_ip" {
  for_each = var.instance
  filter {
    name   = "label"
    values = ["${each.key}.${var.domain}"]
  }
}

locals {
  ips = {
    for k, v in data.vultr_instance.instance_ip : k =>
    {
      hostname    = v.hostname
      external_ip = v.main_ip
    }
  }
}

resource "local_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/ansible_inventory.tpl",
    {
      instancesips = local.ips
    }
  )
  filename = "${path.module}/templates/hosts.yaml"
}
```

---

It's worth also considering the cautionary note in the documentation for the `hashicorp/local` provider, which contributes the `local_file` resource type used above:

> Terraform primarily deals with remote resources which are able to outlive a single Terraform run, and so local resources can sometimes violate its assumptions. The resources here are best used with care, since depending on local state can make it hard to apply the same Terraform configuration on many different local systems where the local resources may not be universally available. See specific notes in each resource for more information.

and in [`local_file`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file) specifically:

> When working with local files, Terraform will detect the resource as having been deleted each time a configuration is applied on a new machine where the file is not present and will generate a diff to re-create it. This may cause "noise" in diffs in environments where configurations are routinely applied by many different users or within automation systems.

It's okay to ignore these warnings when appropriate, but it does mean that the behavior of such a Terraform configuration would not match what Terraform users might expect from other providers: that the desired state and actual state should converge after running `terraform apply` successfully and so future plans will be empty unless the desired state changes. Anyone working with this configuration will need to be trained to expect to see Terraform proposing to create `local_file.ansible_inventory` on each run in a new working directory, even if the desired state hasn't otherwise changed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all.
I have found a solution.

I get this JSON

```json
instances_ips = {
  "app-server" = {
    "external_ip" = "1.2.3.4"
    "hostname" = "app-server.ja.link"
    "internal_ip" = "10.0.0.4"
  }
  "db-server" = {
    "external_ip" = "4.5.6.7"
    "hostname" = "db-server.ja.link"
    "internal_ip" = "10.0.0.3"
  }
}
```

in local.ips

```
data "vultr_instance" "instance_ip" {
  for_each = var.instance
  filter {
    name   = "label"
    values = ["${each.key}.${var.domain}"]
  }
}

locals {
  ips = {
    for k, v in data.vultr_instance.instance_ip : k =>
    {
      hostname    = v.hostname
      external_ip = v.main_ip
    }
  }
}

resource "local_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/ansible_inventory.tpl",
    {
      instancesips = local.ips
    }
  )
  filename = "${path.module}/templates/hosts.yaml"
}
```

and my template now is:

```
# Ansible Inventory
---
hosting:
  hosts:
  %{~ for inst in instancesips  ~}
    ${inst.hostname}:
      ansible_port: 22
      ansible_host: ${inst.external_ip}
  %{~ endfor ~}
```